# How to format a .txt file that is in a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, formatting, text-files

I have a lists of words and their corresponding definitions in `.txt` files. I also have all the data for one entry on one line, so it looks like this:

words.txt

```
The
Quick
Brown
Fox
Jumped
```

and then in my corresponding `answers.txt` I would have

```
An an article of the English Language
An adjective describing speed
An adjective describing color
A noun; a small mammal
Past tense verb
```

So, in my code I import these text files, scan them, and create lists of the data:

```
InputStream is = am.open(numberText);
        scanWords = new Scanner(is);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scanWords.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(scanWords.nextLine());
}
```

My problem is that, some of the 'answers' are extremely long and can get very cramped when I output them; so, how can I edit the lists or insert something in the text files or something that allows for new lines or something in the `.txt` files or the Lists? I cannot convert the lists to arrays because my action listener does not like that. Thanks!

Comment: u can try html formatting textview supports a few html tags

Comment: @droidhot `TextView`? Is he talking about Android? I think he means plain Java... HTML works for `JLabels` too though.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: Where do you print your text? Console, Swing Components, Android, HTML,..?

Comment: @DanielLerps I'm using Android, but I didn't think that would be relevant because I'm just taking the values and throwing them as strings into a Dialog box. I figured I should be formatting before throwing them into the box, and not having to format in the Dialog box, if that makes sense.

Comment: @PaulVargas my desired output is an android Dialog box with proper lines and like 1. bla (\n) 2. blah (\n) 3. blahh and so on, but the \n is not being recognized, and I can understand why; I just don't know how else to format it.

Comment: You can put them in an array and Display in a [Dialog List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList)

Comment: @DanielLerps I want it to be formatted as in I have the word as the title, and then I have the answer as the content, I am only worried about one content at a time, a Dialog List would allow me to put a list in a Dialog box. I want something like the picture at the top of the Dialog page, where it says Erase USB Storage? except my content is much larger.

Comment: @schott12521 Formatting the source is not good programming practice... If you decide to change the style you would have to change the whole source. In a List you could achieve the formatting with a custom adapter that uses a custom layout for the items. Including icons etc...

Comment: @DanielLerps I understand what you're saying, I just don't know how useful it would be, because I am essentially creating a flashcard app, and once you click the initial dialog box, you get an additional box with the definition. A list may be useful for some definitions, but I am not looking to create manual list entries for certain words.

Answer (score 0):

You could before adding the lines to the List check the length of the string and then if it is greater than a certain length say 80 characters, insert an end of line character \n at that position in the String or split the string into two strings and add them separately depending on how you use the List.

Will post code later when I have time.

Comment: Now, I actually go it to scan in to an Array, but my problem still remains, the Array and the Strings are taking the data straight and are not doing anything with \n